# Same Entity to Multiple Tables ORM

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, ebean

This is about migrating a legacy application from JDBC to JPA ORM

How to map a single entity to multiple tables, History, Master and In progress tables of same structure to maintain the versioning of a record in a workflow system. I know about Secondary Table annotation & mappedsuperclass to include multiple tables, But is there another way to do it especially deciding the table name during the runtime?